# My password to login to my "screen" isn't being recognized

Tags: password

My son used my computer last night.  he logged onto it using the Guest User.  He therefore logged off my "screen".  I keyed in my password in the startup screen and it wasn't recognized.  I rekeyed it in a few times incorrectly ( bad I know) but then finally found the CORRECT password and it keeps on "shaking" as it is incorrect.  This is about to drive me crazy and I have spent 1 hr trying to fix it and nothing is working.  please help me!!

Comment: Probably restating is a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

Most probably, and unwillingly, your son modified your input keyboard
or used the <kbd>⇪ caps lock</kbd> key.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the system is stuck in a loop.

Restarting is a good idea allowing it to get sorted out.

This should present you with fresh log in window.

Comment: Since it worked for you please close this question as done.

Comment: To be fair, if you are going to request an acceptance of your answer, then it would be polite to have upvoted the question to which you provided an answer ;)

Comment: And I tough one can not teach new tricks to an old dog :)